# Excel how to make auto SUM form

Tags: vba, excel

I want, then I enter a number (value) in the cell it auto sum(or it's better after clicking "enter" or clicking the button), and the result display in another cell. After that the cell became empty and I can enter next value in the same cell.
For example. I have two cells `A2` and `B2`. In the first, I always enter data, in the second - shows totals. So if we got in cell `B2` the result "230". then I enter in the cell `A2` 100 after press ENTER or some button the result in `B2` become "330" and `A2` after that become empty. And this I can do so many time as I want.

Please help me with the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code you have so far...what all have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a macro that triggers when a cell value changes. The following code is triggered on a worksheet change event and then checks if the cell changed is `A2` and not empty. If so then add the value of `A2` to the current value of `B2` and set `A2` back to null.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("A2")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing _
        And Range("A2") <> "" Then

        Range("B2").Value = Range("B2").Value + Range("A2").Value
        Range("A2").Value = ""
        Range("A2").Select

    End If
End Sub
```

Add this as a macro to your current worksheet and then any numbers you enter into `A2` will be added to the current value of `B2`.

This is just quick example code so you will likely need to modify to suit your specific need. I would research validating entries are numbers and not text also.

Answer (score 1):

PFB for the required code as per your requirement. This macro will sum the value in cell A2 and B2 and give output in cell B2.

```
Sub AutoSumming()

'Declaring variables
Dim Variable1, Total As Long

'Initializing the variables
Variable1 = Range("A2").Value
Total = Range("B2").Value

'Performing the sum
Total = Total + Variable1

'Reassign values back to cells
Range("B2").Value = Total
Range("A2").Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you guys for help the last code work perfectly